# What can I do to access this Table View within a View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have checked out the other posts but I'm not sure next steps here. Here's what I have currently. Do I need to add a tableView variable somewhere else? Connect something differently?

```
class LookbookPostViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.text = postArray[myIndex].title
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
        return postArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LookbookPostViewCell

        cell.postLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.row].title
        print(postArray)
        return cell
    }
    /

}
```

I then have this set up for my connections, but can't seem to get the Table View to recognize any data I'm trying to output.[image]

I also have `class LookbookPostViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var postLabel: UILabel!
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing:

class LookbookPostViewController: UIViewController

to

```
class LookbookPostViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

and then right clicking and making the delegate and datasource, the View Controller, like in this photo here.

[image]